# How to include already compiled executive in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, executable

I have a Eclipse plugin project (plugin to be used in [KNIME](https://www.knime.org/)).
And I need to call some already compiled executable (three different files for different OS).
How can I do to include such files into my Eclipse project? I mean when I want to ship my executable jar file built by this project to other users, I can also ship these files to other users and make them can execute as a Eclipse plugin.

Comment: You might be able to use the [include files in root](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.pde.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Fpde_rootfiles.htm) directives in a Feature but I am not sure if this works for just installing a plugin rather than a full RCP.